# Satellite angular velocity at an angle

Tags: observational-astronomy, orbit, coordinate

Suppose I am observing a satellite that is not at my zenith. I know the altitude(α) and azimuth(γ) of my telescope and I was able to get a relative angular velocity of the satellite.

**Based on this information, is there a way to find the angular velocity when I am underneath the path of the satellite?**

If needed, I know the longitude and latitude of my location as well as the RA and DEC of where the telescope is pointed at.